# How to send base64 strings to POST service - Swift

Tags: swift

I have a problem sending a base64 imagen string to post service in swift 4. This service received "string json post"  and  parameters in base64.

this example:

```
{
  "dato1":"prueba@mail.com",
  "dato2":1,
  "video":{
    "NomVideo":"video.mp4",
    "TipVideo":"mp4",
    "ArchVideo":"Base64"
  },
  "listaImagen":[{
    "NomImagen":"imagen1.jpg",
    "TipImagen":"jpg",
    "ArchImagen":"JKANSDJKASNDASKDNSAJKDNASJKNSA"
  },
  {
    "OrdImagen":2,
    "NomImagen":"imagen2.jpg",
    "TipImagen":"jpg",
    "ArchImagen":"base64"
  }],
  "ObjetoPrincipal":{
    "objetoDato1":"akmdklamd",
    "objetoDato2":"lakmsksamk"
  }
}
```

But when I send parameters in base64, the service doesn't return the answer,  and if do not send parameters in base64 the service responds correctly.

My postservice

```
    class func postJsonWithHeaderAuthorization(_ url :NSString, data :NSString, authorizationParam: String, closure: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()){

    let url = URL(string: url as String)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! )

    request.httpMethod = POST
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue(authorizationParam, forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")


    let data = data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)


    let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest,from: data, completionHandler: { (data,response, error ) in

        closure(data ,response, error)
        return
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

plist configuration:

App transport Security Settings 
    Allow Arbitrary Loads   -   YES

The base64 params is:
k+62cf7vQn8T8o/+tVqAnlz1NIC3JJ2qEHJpjNmlU0wJ1NaVme1ZSmtKyPNADtSP7s17Z4eGNB0wf9OsP/ota8 ........(etc etc)

Comment: did you try postman with same parameters?

Comment: @canister_exister . what do you mean with that?

Comment: @Erik yeah but, i have not received answers with the same problem in https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/231568/enviar-video-y-fotos-por-rest-service-post-swift

Comment: Find program called Postman and check your POST request in this program

Comment: @canister_exister aaa my request is perfectly, the problem is only when send the parameter in base64 value,  If the base64 parameter sent it empty, the service responds well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47177266/4311935 you need to replace + and /

Comment: @canister_exister ty but i I use the method to replace the characters but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

My solution, is resize image and after generate base 64 string, but i changing the service to Alamofire API.

But if I send the whole chain uncompressed then it gives me problems.

Link converter base64 more easy: [Link github base 64 converter](https://gist.github.com/brocoo/6e7466f3138b2e5763ef)

```
let imageRes = imageWithImage(image: imagenTomada, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

    let string64 = imageRes.base64(format: .png)!
```

my Method

```
    private func service(){

    let objetDTO = crearobjetDTO()

    var parametersImagenes: Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> = Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>()

    if objetDTO.LstImagen != nil && objetDTO.LstImagen!.count > 0 {
        for imagenTmp in objetDTO.LstImagen! {

            let parametersImagen: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> =  ["Image Ord":imagenTmp.OrdImagen as AnyObject,"NameImg":imagenTmp.nameImg as AnyObject, "ImageType": imagenTmp.TipImagen as AnyObject, "base64Img": imagenTmp.archv as AnyObject]

            parametersImagenes.append(parametersImagen)
        }

    }


    let params: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [ "param1" : objetDTO.param1 as AnyObject, "param2" : objetDTO.param2 as AnyObject, "LstImagen": parametersImagenes as AnyObject]


    let urlString = "\(miURLservice)"
    let url = URL.init(string: urlString)



    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: params , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers()).responseJSON { response in

        let res = response.data
        switch response.result
        {
        case .success(let json):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let jsonData = json as! NSDictionary
                print(jsonData)


                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                self.ObjResponseDTO = try! decoder.decode(ObjectDTOResponseCustom.self, from: res!)

                print("cotResponse")
                // continue.....
            }

            break
        case .failure(let error):
            //self.errorFailer(error: error)
            print(error)

            break
        }
    }
}

 func headers()->HTTPHeaders{
    return ["Authorization": " \(String(describing: kajndjasndlasjkdnasjkdnsajkdnsajkndasjkd))",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"] as HTTPHeaders
}
```